# Modern Day Chaucer

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, metapuzzles

If you lok, you will fid: There's an empty place
Whee the laws of the wld are cmpletely disgraced.  {2}

In th spring, in this and, the hunting dries out;
And y midsummer's day Hunter's nowhere abou.  {4}

In the fall, just 'fore dan, he again pokes aound
(Though it' soon that he finds that n hunting be foun).  {1}

In the wintr he thrives and ool hunting i good,
Though he hunts not in rairie, nor mountin, nor wood.  {3}

But, alas! on comes spring and he begins to feel umbrage
And again, through the ummer, hibernates in dar slumberage.  {1}

Comment: Still waiting on [English Language & Usage.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) for a verdict on the usage of the word "slumberage."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Stars

Working off the same logic as Nudge Nudge above (upvote!), the five stanzas yield:
1

> L(o)ok, Fi(n)d, Whe(r)e, W(i)ld, C(o)mpletely => Orion

2

> th(e), (l)and, (b)y, abou(t) => Belt

3

> da(w)n, a(r)ound, it'(s), n(o), foun(d) => Sword

4

> wint(e)r, (c)ool, i(s), (p)rairie, mount(a)in => Space

5

> (Y)on, (s)ummer, dar(k) => Sky

Then given the words, take the

> Indicated letter of each word: O(r)ion, Bel(t), (S)word, Sp(a)ce, (S)ky  and rearrange to form STARS, which is of course what Orion's Belt and Sword in Space/Sky are formed of

Comment: This is very close +1! The end result is correct, but the last stanza has three letters (and relates to the subject matter better than Stack Exchange). Check my grammar, is anything amiss?

Comment: Also, I edited/formatted your answer, roll it back if you don't like it, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reformat, I always have trouble with multiline spoilers, had been trying to fix it. And for the hint - I know what the last word is, just need to work out  where the missing letter goes!

Comment: You've got it! I'll add the checkmark eventually, don't worry. BTW, {two spaces} + {carriage return} = {line feed}.

Answer (score 7):

Partial to kick things off:

> The missing letters in each stanza appear to be anagrams:
> If you lo(o)k, you will fi(n)d: There's an empty place
> Whe(r)e the laws of the w(i)ld are c(o)mpletely disgraced.
> ONRIO -> **ORION**
> In th(e) spring, in this (l)and, the hunting dries out;
> And (b)y midsummer's day Hunter's nowhere abou(t). {4}
> ELBT -> **BELT**
> In the fall, just 'fore da(w)n, he again pokes a(r)ound
> (Though it'(s) soon that he finds that n(o) hunting be foun(d)). {1}
> WRSOD -> **SWORD**
> In the wint(e)r he thrives and (w?)ool hunting i(s) good,
> Though he hunts not in (p)rairie, nor mount(a)in, nor wood(s?). {3}
> ESPASW?
> But, alas! on comes spring and he begins to feel umbrage
> And again, through the (s)ummer, hibernates with dar(k?) slumberage.
> SK?